# Autotyping with "enter" and a delay

Tags: text, automation

I'm basically lost. I am looking for a way to automatically type a message and ENTER After it, with a 3 hour delay. I can't seem to find it, AT ALL. I just want to type something and ENTER after it each 3 hours automatically. I have tried to find that for so long and i can't seem to find anything that works and types ENTER and has a delay.

EDIT :: Okay, I used AutoHotKey. It worked, delay worked, but it can't type the "+" symbol. My main purpose required the + symbol and it was the most important in all of it. Why can't AutoHotKey type +'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general-purpose solution to keyboard automation is [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). AHK allows you to write scripts which automatically perform some behavior. The following script will:

1. Wait 3 hours (10800000 milliseconds)
2. Type the message defined in `Message`
3. Press ENTER
4. Repeat until stopped (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

The script:

```
; Change the value to the right of the = to what you want to type
Message = My unquoted awesome message 

; Enable with Ctrl + M
^m::
SetTimer, SendMessage, 10800000 ; 3 hours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3
Return

; Disable with Ctrl + N
^n::
SetTimer, SendMessage, off
return

SendMessage:
Send, %Message%{Enter}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

As Michael suggested AHK is a great option for automating things. You install it then you can create scripts. Basically just open a notepad and save the file as a `someFileName.ahk` which you can then double click to run.

Firstly if you want to have it be different text you might want to user [InputBox](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm) for getting that.

So for example you could do something like:

```
; Kick off the script with Ctrl + M
^m::
InputBox, messageVar, Your Title for the Window, Please enter some text:, , 300, 150

if ErrorLevel
    ; The cancel button was pressed so return
    return

; Negative number will only run once after the specified amount of time. 
SetTimer, SendMessage, -10800000 ; 3 hours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3
return

SendMessage:
Send, %messageVar%{Enter}
Return
```

[image: The output of the InputBox]

If you want it to repeat mix this with Michaels suggestion.